# Pygame window not showing in MacOSX

Tags: python, pygame

I've been using pygame inside a conda environment. The installation went well, but whenever I call flip, it doesn't open any window from the terminal.

Here's the code that's supposed to open the window:

```
screen.blit(background_image, (0, 0))
pygame.display.flip()
pygame.display.update()
```

After pygame starts, it shows this message:

> WARNING:  140: This application, or a library it uses, is using the
>   deprecated Carbon Component Manager for hosting Audio Units. Support
>   for this will be removed in a future release. Also, this makes the
>   host incompatible with version 3 audio units. Please transition to the
>   API's in AudioComponent.h.

Here's the [entire code](https://github.com/cleytonmessias/AIND-Sudoku/blob/master/PySudoku.py).

It's a sudoku game that should display a board with Sudoku being solved.

Comment: flip() and update() are synonyms.  You only need to use one of them.  Show the rest of your code, and we can see what else it might be.

FYI, that warning is just that - a warning from OS X.  It does not have any effect.

Comment: Are these command in a loop ? You must have `pygame.display.update()` in a loop if you want to keep the window alive.

Comment: @Chris and TrakJohson, i've posted the entire code as a link to my repo to give more context.

Comment: I can't tell from that, since it doesn't seem like the complete code, but you're definitely going to see a blank screen if you have pygame.display.flip() followed by pygame.display.update().   They mean the same thing, so you draw the screen, display it, and then immediately replace it with a blank screen.  Remove one of those lines.

Comment: @Chris In the [link](https://github.com/cleytonmessias/AIND-Sudoku/blob/master/PySudoku.py) there the entire repo. I've removed but it continues not showing any screen.

Comment: I'm looking at the link, and I still see:

    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.display.update()

on lines 53 & 54

Comment: @Chris Yes, i've modified in my local version and run it.

Comment: I can't seem to find where main() is defined.  How are you running this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136232/discussion-between-cleyton-and-chris).

Answer (score 0):

(This answer is not directed to the original question but to anyone who might have the same problem)

In the game loop you have to process/check events so that pygame knows your game hasn't crashed:

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 500))

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # process events

    # Update your sprites

    pygame.display.update()
```