# Python crash course doesn't run with no errors

Tags: python

I just get the general "finished with exit code 0" Not sure why its not printing the screen anymore. What would cause this?
If anyone has any input as to why this would be, i'd very much appreciate it so i can move forward & finish the project!
From what ive read, its hard to go on without knowing what actually is causing the "none-error"

```
import sys
import pygame
from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship

class Alieninvasion:
    """overall class to manage game assets & behaviors"""

    def __init__(self):
        """initialize the game & create game resources"""
        pygame.init()
        self.settings = Settings()

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
            (self.settings.screen_width, self.settings.screen_height))
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 600)) # the self.screen portion makes it available in all methods in the class
        pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion!!!") # the self.settings & self.screen can possibly replace the
                                                        # screen & bg_color that doesn't include the settings syntax
        self.ship = Ship(self)

        # set the background color
        self.bg_color = (230, 230, 230)

    def run_game(self):
        """starting the main loop for the game"""
        while True:
            self._check_events()
            self.update_screen()




            # redraw the screen during each pass through the loop
            self.screen.fill(self.bg_color)
            self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)
            self.ship.blitme()

    def _check_events(self):
        """responds to keypresses & mouse events"""
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT():
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key ==pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    # move the ship to the right
                    self.ship.rect.x += 1

            # makes the most recently drawn screen visible. Continually updates the display to show new game position elements and hide old ones.
            pygame.display.flip()


    def update_screen(self):
        """update images on the screen & flip to a new screen"""
        self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)
        self.ship.blitme()

        pygame.display.flip()



if __name__ == 'main':
    # make a game instance and run the game.
    ai = Alieninvasion()
    ai.run_game()

"""the run_game as part of the if block ensures it only runs if the file is called directly"""
```

Comment: Please don't copy paste your question 4 times. It is irritating.

Comment: @Justlearnedit that was a mistype. Do you have any input as to what is causing the "issue"?

Comment: Your program does not specify an exit code. I guess the default one is zero, so you get exit code zero. For your window not showing up, you may take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59572663/pygame-window-not-showing-up or https://python-forum.io/Thread-PyGame-Install-and-Troubleshooting or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42319179/pygame-window-not-showing-in-macosx

Comment: @Justlearnedit thanks for your input! Adding a quit cmd in the end resulted with the same thing unfortunately. Funny enough, it was populating a window until i tried to better organize the code with the _check_events() added. Not sure how that would mess with it, but seemed to maybe have?